# Como agrego un boton funcional? usando html y css

Tags: html, css, html5, botón, interfaz

Básicamente estoy haciendo una pagina de biografía pero basada un poco en la interfaz de facebook y quiero hacer botones que cambie lo que se muestra en la parte de abajo (no la foto y la portada) pero no sé como, he buscado tutoriales y paginas pero ninguna muestra lo que necesito, añado una foto de donde quiero que estén los botones y lo que cambie:(cuadro rojo para los botones que accionan los cambios)(el cuadro negro son las cosas que quiero que cambien)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los botones quiero que vayan debajo del nombre y los 3 divs que hay abajo son lo que quiero que cambien pongo el codigo css:

```css
 *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 4px;
 }
 
 #contenedor{
     width: 1200px;
     height: 1000px;
     background: #D8D8D8;
     margin: 10px auto;
 }
 
 /*#portada1{
     height: 200px;
     width: 150;
     background: #455e9c;
     margin: auto;
 }*/
 
 #portada{
     height: 200px;
     width: 150;
     background: #455e9c;
     border-radius: 20px;
     margin: auto;
     background-image: url(imagenes/foto2.jpg);
 }
 
 /*#portadaf{
     position: absolute;
     height: 200px
     width:150px;
     height: 200px;
     background: #455e9c;
     margin: auto;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background: #455e9c;
 }
 */
 #cosas{
     height: 580px;
     /*background: red;*/
     margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #algo{
     height: 560px;
 /*  margin: 10px*/
     border-radius: 10px;
     width: 570px;
     background: black;
     float: left;
 }
 
 #alg{
     height: 560px;
 /*  margin: 10px*/
     border-radius: 10px;
     width: 570px;
     background: black;
     float: right;
 }
 
 #algo2{
     height: 250px;
     width: 550px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background: white;
 }
 
 #algo3{
     height: 250px;
     width: 550px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background: white;
     margin-top: 10px;
 }
 
 #foto{
     border-radius: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     width: 140px;
     border: black 20px;
     background: #484646;
     float: center;
 }
 
 #fondof{
     height: 150px;
     width: 140px;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 20px
 }
 
 #espacio{
     height: 150px;
     background: #cecece;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #nombre{
     font-size: 50px;
     font-weight: bold 50px;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

y el codigo html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="portada" >
                <div id="fondof"><a href="imagenes/foto1.jpg"><img src="imagenes/foto1.jpg" id="foto"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="espacio">
                <div id="nombre">Mi nombre</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cosas">
                <div id="algo">Algo</div>
                <div id="alg">alg
                    <div id="algo2">Algo2</div>                 
                    <div id="algo3">Algo3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido y gracias por editar tu pregunta, recuerda revisar el documento [ask] que te ayuda para crear preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos!

Answer (score -1):

te ayudaré con el tema de cambiar el contenido pero lo tienes que adaptar a tu proyecto, básicamente lo que pides es un innerHTML que se maneja así

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="cambiar()">con este botón cambiamos lo que esta abajo</button>
        <div id="contenido_a_cambiar"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function cambiar(){
            document.getElementById('contenido_a_cambiar').innerHTML= '<h1>Cambiamos el contenido</h1><h2>Podemos agregar lo que quieras</h2>';
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

al utilizar el innerHTML, puedes agregarle las etiquetas que quieras y el contenido que quieras, te recomiendo que le pases un parámentro a tu función para saber que contenido desplegar, saludos